How do I use gpu for my xgboost model in google colab?
This is the code I am using on my google colab file:
def objective(trial, cv= cv, cv_fold_func=np.average,cost_func = accuracy_score):

    #paramètres suggérés par optuna pour xgboost
    params = {
        "objective": 'multi:softprob',
        "max_depth": trial.suggest_int("max_depth", 2, 10),
        "learning_rate": trial.suggest_float("learning_rate", 1e-4, 1e-1, log=True),
        "min_child_weight": trial.suggest_int("min_child_weight", 1, 10),
        "colsample_bytree": trial.suggest_float("colsample_bytree", 0.2, 1.0),
        "subsample": trial.suggest_float("subsample", 0.2, 1.0),
        "reg_alpha": trial.suggest_float("reg_alpha", 1e-4, 1e2, log=True),
        "reg_lambda": trial.suggest_float("reg_lambda", 1e-4, 1e2, log=True),
        'num_class': y_train.shape[1],
        'tree_method':'hist',
         'device':"cuda",
        'random_state': 41,

    }

    num_boost_round =  trial.suggest_int("num_boost_round", 1000, 8000)

    #clf = XGBClassifier(**params)

    # fit for all folds and return composite accuracy score

    acc_vect = []

    for i, (train_idx, valid_idx) in enumerate(cv.split(X_train, y_train_xgb)):

      d_train = xgb.DMatrix(X_train.iloc[train_idx, :], y_train_xgb[train_idx])
      d_valid = xgb.DMatrix(X_train.iloc[valid_idx, :], y_train_xgb[valid_idx])


      bst = xgb.train(params, d_train, num_boost_round = num_boost_round)

      preds_prob = bst.predict(d_valid)
      preds = np.argmax(preds_prob, axis=1)

      acc_score = accuracy_score(y_train_xgb[valid_idx], preds)

      acc_vect.append(acc_score)



    return cv_fold_func(acc_vect)

n_trials = 50
study = optuna.create_study(direction="maximize")
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=n_trials)


I first chose the execution environment to use the gpu and at first I tried "tree_method" : "gpu_hist" but apparently "tree_method" : "gpu_hist" is deprecated and we now have to use "device" : "cuda" and "tree_method" : "hist" so this is what I did but it still doesn't seem to work (look at the picture of the evolution of the use of my gpu:
.
What should I do to use the gpu resources on colab (I have colab pro)?
Thank you very much for your help !
